Commit con GIT desde python
estoy buscando automatizar un proceso de actualizar un archivo .json y que luego con python necesito commitear y pushear el cambio con git.
Estoy usando la libreria Git Hace rato vengo intentado que haga el push y no lo logra hacer con el json actualizado.
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git commit -m Actualizacion - 2024-11-11 20:02:47.140566
  stdout: 'On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)'

Tengo este error y ya habiendo modificado el json en la misma carpeta sin moverla de lugar, ideas?
Para no poner todo el codigo donde lo edito, voy a usar la ultima parte.
    ListoGuardar=json.dumps(edit,indent=2)
with open(f"{ubi}/db/contenido.json", 'w') as archivo:
    #print(edit,'\n',actualizacion)
    archivo.write(ListoGuardar) #escribimos las modificaciones dentro del json nuevamente.
archivo.close()

#establesco que si se edito el repo
repo.git.add(update=True)

# el mensaje del commit junto al comit 
texto = f"Actualizacion - {datetime.datetime.now()}"
repo.git.commit(f'-m', texto)
print('muere 2')

repo.git.push("--set-upstream", 'origin', 'main')

print('Cambios subidos al repositorio en GitHub') 


Es la primera vez que versionas el archivo?

Dentro del repositorio el archivo se versiono varias veces. Dentro de la copia que se hace de forma local por el codigo, se podria decir que si, ya que nunca se concreta un commit

Claramente tienes un problema durante el git add, el error de git commit es claro, no hay cambios que subir, no hay nada nuevo. En tu código no veo como saber que el archivo ha sido editado como tal, solo veo que dices que un archivo ha sido modificado, y luego haces git add y git commit de la nada, sin verificarlos bien. Y por otro lado, estas usando repo.git, eso tampoco lo veo en el código.

El problema que si es editado.
se agregan mas "items" por asi decirlo y se guarda. Osea el proceso es
Clona->Edita->Reescribe con lo nuevo->guarda->Commit
Si necesitan puedo proporcionar el resto del codigo pero es largo.
Y si checkeo que el archivo sea modificado, ya que lo muestro en consola

Solo para confirmar entonces, es la primera vez que versionas el archivo? (si/no), si es primera vez, al hacer repo.git.add(update=True) solo se agregarán archivos que ya esten siendo rastreados por git, entonces, por eso manda el error de "no hay nada para el commit"... prueba a darle siempre el archivo, a ver si lo agrega, para descartar si es primer versionamiento o no. repo.git.add(f"{ubi}/db/contenido.json")

Hola, perdon por la tardanza pero ya logre solucionarlo con lo que me comentaste gracias!

Agregaré como respuesta entonces, una explicación del problema/solución como respuesta.

Para explicar el problema/solución, tendremos que atenernos al error en sí.
Los errores siempre dan una explicación clara, de lo que está ocurriendo, incluso cuando nosotros intentamos hacer algo diferente.
Al momento de ejecutar el comando, el error nos menciona claramente que no hay nada que actualizar, no hay dato nuevo en lo que queremos subir.
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git commit -m Actualizacion - 2024-11-11 20:02:47.140566
  stdout: 'On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)'

Teniendo claro esto, que el error nos ha dicho el problema (no hay nada nuevo), entonces nos enfocamos en el comando que tratamos de ejecutar. El error mismo lo detalla:
git commit -m Actualizacion - 2024-11-11 20:02:47.140566

Pero, además del git commit, acá tenemos un cambio al staging, esto es, antes de realizar el commit, una preparación del mismo:
repo.git.add(update=True)

Esto es el equivalente a realizar: git add --update
La función de --update es que actualiza únicamente los archivos que ya están siendo rastreados por Git (es decir, archivos que ya han sido añadidos al repositorio anteriormente). No incluye nuevos archivos no rastreados.
Entonces...
Sabiendo que el error nos menciona que "no hay nada nuevo", podemos saber que el archivo que se trata de actualizar, no está siendo rastreado aún, por lo que primero, debemos realizar el versionamiento de este, directamente para estar más seguros.
repo.git.add(f"{ubi}/db/contenido.json")

De este modo, incluimos el archivo, y posteriormente, el mismo será rastreado por git, por lo que luego debería funciona sin problemas durante el uso de update.
También, como dato extra, podríamos realizar la verificación de si el archivo ya existe y se actualiza, o si es primera vez que se sube.
#Verificamos +si el archivo ya está siendo rastreado por Git
if archivo in repo.git.ls_files().split('\n'):
    #El archivo ya está rastreado, actualizarlo
    repo.git.add(update=True)
    print(f"El archivo '{archivo}' ha sido actualizado.")
else:
    #El archivo no está rastreado, lo agregamos por primera vez
    repo.git.add(archivo)
    print(f"El archivo '{archivo}' ha sido agregado como nuevo.")

#Luego realizamos el commit que necesitamos

